# How to locate the element for the below html using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to find xpath for the below html tag. but not able to locate in selenium.as i am beginner i need some help and suggestions. getting error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='react-autosuggest__input react-autosuggest__input--open']"}
(Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
```

This is the HTML element.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="react-autowhatever-1" class="react-autosuggest__input react-autosuggest__input--open" placeholder="From" value="">
```

I have tried and made this xpath for the above HTML.but the same is throwing error.

```
//*[@class='react-autosuggest__input react-autosuggest__input--open']
```

i expect the output of the above xpath to locate the element in selenium but in actual i am getting error.

Comment: //input[@class='react-autosuggest__input react-autosuggest__input--open'] did you try this way. ? Please conform there is another input type is exist or not with same class name.

Comment: Hi @Dhru'soni . i have tried this just now. but getting some error. "Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //input[@class='react-autosuggest__input react-autosuggest__input--open'] '] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//input[@class='react-autosuggest__input react-autosuggest__input--open'] ']' is not a valid XPath expression."

Answer (score 0):

The element seems to be a [React](https://reactjs.org/) element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.react-autosuggest__input.react-autosuggest__input--open[placeholder='From']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='react-autosuggest__input react-autosuggest__input--open' and @placeholder='From']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB thanks for the solution. i have tried with both the solution.but getting below error."Traceback (most recent call last):
   <module>
    from_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='react-autosuggest__input react-autosuggest__input--open' and @placeholder='From']")))
  File "C:\Users\Anurag Jangde\PycharmProjects\Selenium_python\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:"

Comment: _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _expected-conditions_. Debug your code through `find_element_by_*` in-conjunction with `time.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB i am unable to locate the element with both the solution.Thanks for your help !

Comment: Check if the element is within an `<iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

Try with a WebDriverWait, only set the longer wait, e.g.:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='From']")))
```